Removing GitHub Copilot pop-up settings from VS Code
I keep getting this pop-up(the line with the smiley, debug, delete icons and so on) of option icons on selecting a line of code in my VS code. It is a little bit annoying as it causes problems in dragging and selecting texts. How can I disable this?
I tried removing a bunc of plugins but it still did not help.


That must be from an extension.  Run the Help: Start Extension Bisect command to figure out which one to disable. (May be one with 'code lens' in the title).

Turns out this is a Github Copilot extension feature. To disable it, go to extension settings > Edit in JSON and change the following to false
"github.copilot-labs.showBrushesLenses": false
